# Windows 10 activation issue

Tags: windows, windows-10

2 days ago after i upgraded my windows 8.1 to windows 10 system failed
after a startup that took longer than usually, when i logged in computer was barely responding, very slow until it just lags and then gave me an error.
No solution found online could help so i decided to install windows 10 again which needed a previous system installed.

I installed windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit without a key and wanted to install windows 10 after that. Now I'm struggling to find a way to activate that windows 10 because I don't have a key of my windows 8.1 or a backup and all the common keys aren't quite working for me.

Please help, I'm desperate now, because i know that I've probably made some major mistake that leads to all the problem. Is there any way i can activate my windows without buying another genuine copy?

Comment: I think I should answer my comment to answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a OEM machine (from retailer) and it came with a genuine Windows 8.1 copy, your product key may be hidden in your BIOS. Check [this article](http://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-retrieve-windows-8-oem-product-key-from-bios) frow which you have sone links to download NirSoft's ProduKey or RWEverything to reveal your genuine product key hidden in your BIOS.

Comment: Well, the problem is not yet solved, because the code from the RWEverything isn't working. I have no idea what to do now.

Comment: Remember that the product key you extracted is for Windows 8.1 only. It will not work with any other Windows OS. If you still have the recovery partition, restore your PC to Windows 8.1 . If you don't have a recovery partition install a copy of Windows 8.1

Comment: I did install a copy of 8.1 and it didn't work. My only guess is that i installed wrong bit. I'm currently booting a pendrive for 32 bit(previously tried 64) and will see if it works.

Comment: What was the original OS ?

Comment: It's my friend's laptop and she's said that 8.1 was the original.

Comment: Maybe you mistakenly typed in a wrong key even if it's a good one. It happened to me to enter a good key and not working. Pay attention to every character.Also try to use the program again or use another program.

Comment: Did check it like 3 times. Now something's wrong with my pendrive and PC isn't booting from it. I select booting from pendrive but it starts windows normally. I'll let it rest for 5 minutes and try again.

Comment: Try changing the boot order in your BIOS. If it doesn't work, and if you have a new CD, use [PloP boot manager](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16822/boot-from-a-usb-drive-even-if-your-bios-wont-let-you/) ,burn the iso to a CD and boot from CD then at the menu boot from USB.

Comment: Well, windows 8.1 32 bits doesnt seem to be working too

Comment: So i downloaded the Windows 8 setup from Microsoft website and entered the key showed by RWE and it says that this product key cannot be used to install a retail version of Windows 8. I'm confused.

Comment: I clearly understeand now. A OEM key does not activate a retail copy of Windows. You need to restore it from recovery partition or contact manufacturer support to help you out.Or get a volume license copy of Windows.

Comment: There is no recovery partition but i got an OEM copy of Windows and will try it out

Comment: The OEM copy works i think, because there is no text like "activate Windows"

Comment: If that's the case and you don't see "activate windows " in settings, you can safely upgrade to Windows 10 and your problem is solved.

Comment: I'm currently doing so :)